# How to test code in rescue clause in rspec

Tags: rspec

I have the following pattern in my code:

The point is that we need errors to be silently logged, but tests need fail if there is a mistake in the code.

```
begin
  self.a_method_call
  some_other_object.a_method_that_has_been_refactored
rescue StandardError => e
  Rails.logger.error e.backtrace
end
```

If an error is thrown because of an interaction between `self.a_method_call` and `some_other_object.a_method_that_has_been_refactored` then the rescue standard error will silence any error and pass any test that is testing the code block. How can I silence the rescue so that tests will fail if there is a mistake in the code in the begin clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error logging is part of its functionality. Instead of silencing the rescue, capture the error logging.

As written you can do this by [mocking the logger](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs). Use [`with`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-9/docs/setting-constraints/matching-arguments) to configure what arguments you expect `Rails.logger.error` to receive. Since you don't know exactly what will be received, you can use various matchers like [`instance_of`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-9/docs/built-in-matchers/type-matchers) to check you got what `backtrace` returns, an Array.

```
it 'logs the backtrace as an error' do
  # This comes before you call the method to set up the mock which expects
  # to be called.
  expect(Rails.logger).to receive(:error)
    .with(instance_of(Array))  

  thing.some_method
end
```

Because this replaces `Rails.logger`, if anything else in the process of `thing.some_method` calls `Rails.logger` the test will fail.

We can make this easier with a small refactoring. Instead of using `Rails.logger` directly, make it an attribute.

```
class SomeClass
  attr_accessor :logger

  def initialize
    @logger = Rails.logger
  end

  def some_method
    a_method_call
    some_other_object.a_method_that_has_been_refactored
  rescue StandardError => e
    logger.error e.backtrace
  end
end
```

Now we can specifically mock what is returned from `thing.logger`.

```
it 'logs the backtrace as an error' do
  # This comes before you call the method to set up the mock which expects
  # to be called.
  expect(thing.logger).to receive(:error)
    .with(instance_of(Array))  

  thing.some_method
end
```

Comment: great answer. thanks. I can fix this by expecting rails.logger not to be called.